Are there some propositions that cannot be expressed easily in first order logic and in higher order logics?
Are there some propositions, i.e. statements that are either true or false, that cannot be expressed easily in first order logic and in higher order logics? I ask because of the following: Let C be the predicate cat. Let D be the predicate dog. Let M be the predicate mammal. So, we have ∀x(Cx-Mx)∧∀y(Dy→My)→∀x∀y(Cx∧Dy→Mx∧My). Note, ∀x∀y(Cx∧Dy→Mx∧My) signifies all cats and dogs are mammals. If I were to negate all cats and dogs are mammals, I should get some cats and dogs are not mammals. However, if I were to negate ∀x∀y(Cx∧Dy→Mx∧My), I would get ∃x∃y(Cx∧Dy∧(¬Mx∨¬My)), which doesn’t seem to match some cats and dogs are not mammals.

See SOL for examples of expression that SOL can manage while FOL cannot. Not regarding cats and dogs but mathematical properties.

I don't see the problem with your example. ∀x∀y(Cx∧Dy → Mx∧My) says that all cats and all dogs are mammals. Strictly speaking, it would be better to write it as ∀x(Cx → Mx) ∧ ∀y(Dy → My) but as long as we understand that there is at least one cat and at least one dog it won't matter. Now, as you say, its negation gives ∃x∃y(Cx∧Dy∧(¬Mx∨¬My)). This states that there is at least one cat and at least one dog and one or both of them is not a mammal. That's correct.
If you want the result to state instead that some dogs are not mammals and also some cats are not mammals, then you would need two negations: not all dogs are mammals and not all cats are mammals. Consider this example. Alice says: All crows and bears are black. Bob denies this. For Bob to be correct, there only needs to be one bear that is not black. He is not committed to the existence of a non-black crow as well.
The answer to the question you state in the heading is that there are lots of kinds of propositions that first order logic and even higher order logics cannot express.
Many of those can be expressed by adopting an extension of first order logic, e.g. modal logic, temporal logic, conditional logics, plural quantification, intensional and hyperintensional logics, etc.
Some can be expressed by introducing some additional theory such as set theory, arithmetic or probablity theory.
Some can be expressed using non-classical logics, e.g. fuzzy logic, many valued logics, free logic, nonmonotonic logics, etc.
Even then, there are many residual issues, such as with propositional attitudes, intentional verbs and indexicals.
